# Granting permission to users on different schema

Tags: oracle

I have tables in Schema A. I created views in Schema B using the tables in schema A.

I want to grant permissions to a user to select the data from view in Schema B.

For this to work i know we have to enable the grant option on tables in Schema A to user B.
But I want to do it in a single script (This script has to be in schema B). Is there a way to do this using the user name/password of schema A.

Comment: Doesn't make sense - scripts don't exist in a schema, they're just a list of commands that the user you're connecting to the instance has the privilege to run.  IIRC grant statements are per object (IE: table).  Please rephrase your question so it's more clear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 9):

It's not unusual to want to have a single script to deploy a change.  The thing is, such a script needs to be run by a power user, because it needs to have system privileges at the ANY level.  This usually means a DBA account, preferably an application account but otherwise SYSTEM or SYS.

So the script you want would look like this:

```
grant select on user_a.t23 to user_b
/
grant select on user_a.t42 to user_b
/
create view user_b.v_69 as
select t23.col1, t42.col2
from   user_a.t42
       join user_a.t23
           on (t42.id = t23.id)
/
grant select on user_b.v_69 to user_c
/
```

A common scenario is that we have a suite of individual scripts which have been written to be run by different users but which we now need to bundle up into a single deployment.  The original scripts don't contain the schema names, and there are many good reasons why we wouldn't want to hardcode them in the scripts.

One way to build that master script is to use change the CURRENT_SCHEMA syntax:

```
alter session set current_schema=USER_A
/
@run_grants_to_userb.sql

alter session set current_schema=USER_B
/
@create_view69.sql
@run_grants_to_userc.sql
```

We still need a DBA user to run the master script.  One advantage of switching the current schema is that it allows us to deploy objects like database links, which through a quirk of syntax cannot have the schema name in their declaration.  One gotcha is that the user doesn't change, so a script which employs the USER pseudo-column may produce unwanted results.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the USER keyword resolves at runtime and not at deploy time. Hence if you had a column which showed the "user", it would return the ID of the user executing the SQL, not the user who deployed the view. Still - I understand the point you're making in principle, even if the specific example isn't relevant.

Comment: @cartbeforehorse - to be honest I can't remember the point I was trying to make all those years ago. I think I had in mind scripts which did something like `create table t1 as select * from t where col1 = user;` .

Comment: Yes - if you created a table and pre-populate it with data which was filtered by "user", then the data loaded into that table would only be relevant to the user creating the table (not users who access it subsequently).  But that's quite a specific use-case :-P  *[PS Sorry to dig up the past - I don't look at time-stamps before replying. I assume everything here is timeless]*

Answer (score 7):

Simply Run the query

> GRANT INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLE1 TO SCHEMA2;

Answer (score 3):

Only by connecting as user A at some point. You can still do it in one script if you really want to:

```
connect userA/passwordA
grant select on my_table to userB;
connect userB/passwordB
create view my_view as select * from userA.my_table;
```

Of course now you have a script lying around which exposes two sets of user credentials to anyone who can read it. So something to think hard about before doing in production, for example.

If you want other users to be able to select from the view, you don't need to grant explicit permissions on `userA.my_table` to them; as long as the view owner can see the underlying table, other users just need to be able to see the view. Which is often kinda the point (or one of them) as you can restrict the view to only expose selected data from the underlying table to the rest of the world. I assume you have a reason for not creating the view in schema A.

I'm not sure if you're really asking about granting select to user B with admin option so that user B can then grant select on user A's table to other people. If that's possible, it doesn't sound like a good idea, and isn't necessary for the view to work.

Comment: `SYSTEM` can also apply the grants, you don't necessarily have to log in as userA. This way you don't need the passwords in the script.

Comment: True, I guess I was assuming that wanting to use the userA credentials meant they didn't have DBA privs. I read it as they are userB but happen to know userA too. How unusual for an arbitrary assumption to be problematic...

Answer (score 3):

Let user A grant select on his tables to B and include the 'grant option'.

As user A:

```
GRANT select ON table TO user_b WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Let user B grant select on his views to user A and include the 'grant option'.

As user B:

```
GRANT select ON view TO user_a WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

As user A:

```
GRANT select on user_b.view TO user_c;
```

This allows user A to pass this grant on to other users.

Comment: B can only grant select on the view to A if A has already granted the WITH GRANT OPTION on their table.  In addition, it is not necessary for A to have select on the view in order for C to have select on the view.

Comment: I added the WITH GRANT OPTION on the table from A to B. I think A needs select on the view to pass this grant on to C (as stated in the question, "Is there a way to do this using the user name/password of schema A."

Comment: Hmmm, that will work.  The question is contradictory as OMG Ponies pointed out, specifying a script in User B that uses the username/password of User B.