# Grant Access to Schema

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

In oracle, how can i give grant to 'A' user to access 'B' schema?

Also, Is it possible to give, 'SELECT, EXECUTE AND VIEW' grant to A user on B schema?

Comment: you should refer to the documentation before posting such a question

Comment: i did and i could not find.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198952/correct-way-to-give-users-access-to-additional-schemas-in-oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198952/correct-way-to-give-users-access-to-additional-schemas-in-oracle) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220094/granting-permission-to-users-on-different-schema

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198952/correct-way-to-give-users-access-to-additional-schemas-in-oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198952/correct-way-to-give-users-access-to-additional-schemas-in-oracle) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220094/granting-permission-to-users-on-different-schema

Comment: sorry but these are not my answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'GRANT ALL ON '||table_name||' TO BOB;'
FROM   ALL_TABLES
WHERE  OWNER = 'ALICE';
```

Comment: i just want to grant 'SELECT, EXECUTE AND VIEW' not all

Comment: Use select or execute or view instead ALL in query

Comment: @sezercan      accept this answer if it is usefull to you

Comment: you can not view or execute table.

Comment: Do you have the grant to the other user's table directly? Or is it via a role? You will need the privilege to be granted directly in order to create an object (view, procedure, etc.) that references the other table. As a quick test, in SQL*Plus

`SQL> set role none;
SQL> select count(*) from otherschema.othertable;`
If that fails, then the problem is that you have been granted privileges on the table via a role.